# Espresso Instrumentation Tests not running with dagger 2. No Tests were found

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, dagger-2

I am a newbie to dagger 2, Espresso Instrumentation tests were running fine with Roboguice and I moved the application to dagger2 and now Espresso Test not running(Unit Tests are working fine). 
Here is stack trace:

```
android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner Client not ready yet.
Started running tests
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'
Empty test suite.
```

Any help will be appreciated. Anyone has espresso working with dagger 2?

Comment: how I can help you without code. Please put whole class

Comment: what's in the logcat for the `ClassNotFoundException` exception?